# MySQL Retrieving data from two tables using inner join syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

My two tables are

```
Entry
event_id   competitor_id   place
101        101             1
101        102             2
101        201             3
101        301             4
102        201             2
103        201             3
```

second table lists prizes on offer for the events

```
Prize
event_id   place          money
101        1              120
101        2              60
101        3              30
102        1              10
102        2              5
102        3              2
103        1              100
103        2              60
103        3              40
```

From this I am looking to show all the information from the Entry table alongside the amount of money they won for their respected placing. If they failed to place in the money then a 0 will be displayed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the criteria for "*If they failed to place in the money*"?

Comment: For example in this case, there is no record of a prize for 4th place in event 101.

Comment: then for the 4th place, zero will be displayed as what OP wants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT  a.Event_ID, 
        a.Competitor_ID,
        a.Place,
        COALESCE(b.money, 0) as `Money`
FROM    entry a left join prize b
            on  (a.event_id = b.event_ID) AND
                (a.place = b.Place)
```

hope this helps.

```
EVENT_ID    COMPETITOR_ID   PLACE   MONEY
101           101            1      120
101           102            2       60
101           201            3       30
101           301            4        0   -- << this is what you're looking for
102           201            2        5
103           201            3       40
```

Comment: This looks more like what is being asked for, to give a 0 value for competitors that received no money.

Comment: if i understood his question clearly, this will give answer to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM Entry NATURAL LEFT JOIN Prize;
```

If you absolutely want `0` instead of `NULL` for the "money" when no prize was won (but how can you differentiate between a prize of 0 and no prize?):

```
SELECT Entry.*, COALESCE(money, 0) AS money FROM Entry NATURAL LEFT JOIN Prize;
```

See them both [on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76a5c/2).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select e.*, coalesce(p.money, 0) money from entry e
left join prize p
on e.event_id = p.event_id and e.place = p.place
```

You can play with the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b190/2).